# Changes reflected in the database yet hibernate doesn't pick them

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, oracle11g

I have very little knowledge of hibernate and am trying to debug an issue with code involving hibernate. The issue is hibernate is unable to pick up changes made to the database. I can query the database and see the changes present but for some reason hibernate is unable to pick it up.

The data in question is a child entity (so to speak) and has the following annotations on it:
`@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "parent", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)`
`@Fetch(FetchMode.SUBSELECT)`

However, in the code I see that this entity is being fetched reflectively using the  `JavassistLazyInitializer` class. The entire operation is wrapped in a Transaction (a custom class having subset of functionality defined in `JTA`, without any nested transactions).

My questions are:

1) How to view the subselect query? I've set the log4j file to spit out everything using `log4j.logger.org.hibernate=TRACE` but still can't see the subselect query.

2) The data which hibernate can't retrieve is written by another hibernate transaction using `EntityManager#persist()`. I also see `flush()` being called after persist(). Given all this, is there a scenario in which the new hibernate transaction won't read the values written by the previous transaction?

Any suggestions/ideas/tips to debug through this are welcome. Thanks.

Comment: What about `transaction.commit()`? Is it being called after `flush()`?

Comment: Yes, it's being called after flush().

Comment: Set `hibernate.show_sql = true` to see all queries generated by Hibernate. You may also like to set `hibernate.format_sql = true` to see them formatted.

Comment: Is that specified in the log4j file or somewhere else? I did that but still can't see the subselect query. I wonder if it has something to do with reflection.

Comment: You need to specify that in Hibernate properties not log4j. If you are using `Spring`, it should be somewhere in your spring config files (where you configure Hibernate).

Comment: All the hibernate related jars are hibernate-annotations-3.4.0.GA, hibernate-core 3.3.1.GA, hibernate-commons-annotations 3.3.0.ga, hibernate-entitymanager 3.4.0.GA. I don't see any Spring references anywhere.